# Python: How do I associate Tkinter text tags with information and access them in an event?

Tags: python, tags, tkinter

I am using a Text widget in tkinter and have associated some tags with it like this:

```
textw.tag_config( "err", background="pink" );

textw.tag_bind("err", '<Motion>', self.HoverError);
```

Basically all the text that contains an error is tagged with "err". Now I want to access the associated error message with the hovered tag but I don't know how to know which tag was hovered.

```
def HoverError( self, event ):
   # Get error information
```

If I could just extract the range of the hovered tag it would be solved. Any ideas of how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Motion` `event` has attributes associated with it, and one of those is the x, y coordinates of the mouse. The `Text` widget can interpret those coordinates as indices, so you can grab the instance of the tag nearest the index where the mouse is using the `tag_prevrange` method.

Here's an example:

```
def hover_over(event):

    # get the index of the mouse cursor from the event.x and y attributes
    xy = '@{0},{1}'.format(event.x, event.y)

    # find the range of the tag nearest the index
    tag_range = text.tag_prevrange('err', xy)

    # use the get method to display the results of the index range
    print(text.get(*tag_range))


root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

text.insert(1.0, 'This is the first error message ', 'err')
text.insert(END, 'This is a non-error message ')
text.insert(END, 'This is the second error message ', 'err')
text.insert(END, 'This is a non-error message ')
text.insert(END, 'This is the third error message', 'err')

text.tag_config('err', background='pink')
text.tag_bind('err', '<Enter>', hover_over)

root.mainloop()
```

The `tag_prevrange` method will give you unwanted results if two tags bump up against each other (it will seek to the end of the tag, as there won't be a natural break), but depending on how you insert into the `Text` widget, this may not be an issue.